# How can i change the position of substring within a string in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I have this into a .txt:
xxxxxxxx,yyyyyyyyyyyy,zzzzzzzzz

How can i change the positions of y and z?
For example:
xxxxxxxx,zzzzzzzzz,yyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: So, if i have this in a .txt file:  xxxxxxxx,yyyyyyyyyyyy,zzzzzzzzz  i need to pass this string in a List for change the positions?

Comment: No, you need to create a new string.

Comment: `parts = s.split(',');new_s = ','.join(parts[:1] + parts[1::-1])`

Comment: Peter, you are devil :D

Comment: @PeterWood that's was a lot of help, its not exactly what i want but i work with this. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that last slice was wrong: `parts = s.split(',');new_s = ','.join(parts[:1] + parts[-1:-3:-1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string into a list of substrings:

```
>>> s = 'xxxxxxxx,yyyyyyyyyyyy,zzzzzzzzz'

>>> parts = s.split(',')
>>> parts
['xxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyyyy', 'zzzzzzzzz']
```

Then you can re-order:

```
>>> reordered = parts[0] + parts[2] + parts[1]
>>> reordered
['xxxxxxxx', 'zzzzzzzzz', 'yyyyyyyyyyyy']
```

And rejoin:

```
>>> ','.join(reordered)
'xxxxxxxx,zzzzzzzzz,yyyyyyyyyyyy'
```

Comment: This is more clearly than: parts = s.split(',');new_s = ','.join(parts[:1] + parts[-1:-3:-1]). But thanks again!